Filled contour plot in PGFPlots from (X,Y,Z) data
I'm trying to create a filled contour plot similar to this one I generated using Matlab:

I have a text file which contains the (X,Y,Z) data {https://pastebin.com/jHt4FJMu}.
I've looked at various other posts regarding this issue but they either don't compile or don't seem to produce what I need. I've also tried using matlab2tikz but this produces 14,000 lines of code, which is not efficient. For the record I'm using overleaf to compile the document. I know there may be issues with PDF viewers but I can't even get something similar to what I need.
I have tried using
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
colorbar, 
point meta max=7.6e5, 
point meta min=6.0e5,]
\addplot3[
    contour filled={number = 100,
    labels={false}},
    mesh/rows=56,
    mesh/cols=57,
    mesh/check=false] 
    table {0degrees_data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

which gives the following figure

I also tried using surf
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
colorbar, 
point meta max=7.6e5, 
point meta min=6.0e5,]
\addplot3[
    surf,shader=interp,
    samples=100,
    mesh/rows=56,
    mesh/cols=57,
    mesh/check=false] 
    table {0degrees_data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

which produces

Similarly when I use shader=flat with the surf option:
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90},
colorbar, 
point meta max=7.6e5, 
point meta min=6.0e5,]
\addplot3[
    surf,
    shader=flat,
    samples=100,
    mesh/rows=56,
    mesh/cols=57,
    mesh/check=false] 
    table {0degrees_data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

I get

Thanks in advance,
Emma

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

It would be better to post a minimal (non-)working example showing what you tried. If the dataset is too large, you can maybe just show a few lines.

I think, you could use something like \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}] \addplot3 [surf, shader=flat, mesh/rows=57] table {data.dat}; \end{axis}. You need to specify the number of rows (or columns) though, since in your data there are no empty lines to divide the data into groups.

Thank you for your comments, I have edited the post.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={0}{90},
colormap={CM}{
color=(white)
color=(blue!50!black)
color=(blue!50!white)
color=(cyan!70!white)
color=(orange!50!yellow)
color=(yellow)
},
]
\addplot3[
mesh/rows=57, mesh/cols=56,
contour filled={number=100, labels={false}},
point meta max=7.6e5, 
point meta min=6.0e5,
] table {0degrees_data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

With colormap Parula from here: PGFPlots: How to reproduce MATLAB colorbar and make it span multiple plots?

